# Repainting/Revalidating JPanel wont work

Tags: java, swing, awt, java-2d, mixing

I am unclear on how to repaint a JPanel in my existing code. I also dont understand how paintComponent is being called. Firstly, I would simply like to clear the JPanel but I cannot even do that.

I want to be able to press the "Next Move" button and repaint the JPanel given a change in the grid I am reading colours from. I am having trouble changing the JPanel at all via the calls, revalidate(), removeAll(), and repaint() to my tiles JPanel.

I call these and nothing happens to the existing JPanel below of a tetris grid (tiles) (pictured)..

In the below code i have a nested class that extends JPanel and the setup function creates the window taking in a 2d arraylist grid and constructing the original grid.

How do I at least clear the JPanel or even better redraw with a new grid... I was thinking a method:

```
    public void redraw(Grid g) {
        removeAll();
                    getColor(); //gets new grid of tiles
                    repaint();
        revalidate();
    }
```

Inside the nested JPanel class, but this doesnt seem to change the JPanel at all not even clear the current drawing.

[image: Tetris Board reading in original grid]

```
 public class BoardGraphics {

    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Color>> colours;

    private final int width;

    private int height;

    private JFrame display;

    private TetrisSquares tiles;

    private Container c;

    public BoardGraphics(int width, int height,
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> grid) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        colours = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Color>>(width);
        setColor(grid);
        setup();
    }

    public void setup() {
        System.out.println("Let the Tetris Begin");
        display = new JFrame("Tetris Agent");



        final TextArea welcome = new TextArea("Welcome to Tetris", 2, 10,
                TextArea.SCROLLBARS_NONE);

        welcome.setBackground(Color.black);
        welcome.setForeground(Color.red);
        welcome.setFont(new Font("monospaced", 0, 11));
        welcome.setEditable(false);

        Button btnStart = new Button("Next Move");
        btnStart.setFocusable(false);



        tiles = new TetrisSquares(TetrisBoard.BOARD_WIDTH, height);

        c = new Container();
        c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        c.add(welcome, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        c.add(tiles);
        c.add(btnStart,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
           {
             tiles.removeAll();
             tiles.revalidate();
           }
        });


        final Container main = new Container();

        main.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        display.add(c);



        display.pack();

        display.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        display.setVisible(true);
    }

    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Color>> getBoard() {
        return colours;
    }

    public void setColor(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> grid) {
        ListIterator<Integer> li;

        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            colours.add(new ArrayList<Color>());
            li = grid.get(i).listIterator();
            for (int j = 0; j <= height; j++) {
                int n = 0;
                if(li.hasNext()) {
                    n = li.next();

                }
                switch (n) {
                case 1:
                    colours.get(i).add(Color.red);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    colours.get(i).add(Color.pink);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    colours.get(i).add(Color.orange);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    colours.get(i).add(Color.yellow);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    colours.get(i).add(Color.green);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    colours.get(i).add(Color.cyan);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    colours.get(i).add(Color.blue);
                    break;
                default:
                    colours.get(i).add(Color.gray);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }



    public class TetrisSquares extends JPanel {

        public int width;
        public int height;

        public TetrisSquares(int width, int height) {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = width;
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width * 20, height * 20));
        }

        public void redraw() {
            removeAll();
            //add your elements
            //revalidate();
            //repaint();
        }


        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) g;
            graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            /*
             * tiles.width = getSize().width / width; tiles.height =
             * getSize().height / 800;
             * 
             * insets.left = (getSize().width - width * tiles.width) / 2;
             * insets.right = insets.left; insets.top = 0; insets.bottom =
             * getSize().height - height * tiles.height;
             */
            Dimension size = getSize();
            Insets insets = getInsets();

            int w = size.width - insets.left - insets.right;
            int h = size.height - insets.top - insets.bottom;

            int tileWidth = w / width;
            int tileHeight = w / width;

            ListIterator<Color> li;

            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
                li = colours.get(i).listIterator();
                int n = 20;

                while(li.hasNext()) {
                    --n;
                    int x = (int) (i * tileWidth);
                    int y = (int) (n * tileHeight);
                    graphics.setColor(li.next());
                    graphics.fillRect(x, y, tileWidth, tileHeight);
                    graphics.setColor(Color.black);
                    graphics.drawRect(x, y, tileWidth, tileHeight);
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by having a read through [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) to gain a better understanding of the painting system.

`removeAll` removes all the child components from the container, this isn't really going to help you in this situation...

`revalidate` deals with the layout subsystem and updating the container hierarchy in response to changes in the container contents, again, not really going to help...

In you `paintComponent` method, you are referencing a `ArrayList` called `colours`, which is used paint the squares.  You need to reset this list to stop the `paintComponent` method from filling in the colors

Your `redaw` method should look more something like...

```
public void redraw() {
    colours.clear();
    repaint();
}
```